# Download file to my computer using Git Bash?

Tags: windows, git, bash, amazon-web-services, ssh

I make a SSH connection to my server.

I need to download a zip file that is on AWS, but I do not know how can I do it.
I do not know the necessary command and the sintaxis.

By the way, I'm working on Windows 10 and I'll have to do it using Git Bash.

Greetings

Comment: you can use `scp`. Its pretty simple
`scp <server-ip-or-name>:<file-path-on-the-server> <file-path-on-your-local-machine-where-you-want-to-save-it>`
I use something like this:
`scp  ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxcompute-1.amazonaws.com:~/my-file-on-server ./`
It saves my file in the current directory

Comment: As you're running on Windows, you could install WinSCP. Or you could install PuTTY and then use pscp (https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter5.html). WinSCP is simpler.

Answer (score 6):

You can find this answer at 
http://www.compciv.org/recipes/cli/downloading-with-curl/

If that website is active, please read the answer there in case I missed details. Otherwise:

Use the curl command and output a file to your current working directory.

`curl http://some.url --output some.file`